# How to get Xpath of div contains attribute with value

Tags: jquery, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, xpath-2.0

[image]
I am trying to locate an element for my selenium tests. I tried to write the following xpath but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I tried :

```
//div[contains(@tb-test-id, 'Distribution')]
```

Note:

I am aware of the fact that I can use the CssSelector and also Xpath based on the concrete placeholder id as the parent node : tabZoneId115 and also using the relative paths in Xpath. My scenario here is little complicate as I want to click on several other elements on this page and likewise i will need to write elements for hundreds of test cases. So I am planning to write one test case and trying to provide data driven excel sheet, so that people can maintain the test cases by only adding the title of text box, in this case 'DISTRIBUTION' is the title of the text box report.

Please guide me on how I locate the right element for me click. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by *"doesn't seem to work for me"* ? What exactly do you want to select?

Comment: I receive an error while running from selenium webdriver. Error : Unable to locate the element. I want to select the title section that reads "Distribution". Its not a clickable element or anything, however I am clicking on the title area that basically selects the underlying data for me to download on that web page. To keep it simple, I would like to click on the title that says "Distribution".

Comment: Might be that the Html tag or the attribute are not there from the beginning. Set up time out so that Selenium would keep trying to get the element for a number of seconds before raising this error. Are you using Selenium with JavaScript?

Comment: what you get driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[contains(@tb-test-id, 'Distribution')]")).click();

Answer (score 0):

You have given all the required details and have also probhably Answered your own Question.

You could have used the `CssSelector` or also `Xpath` as well. You can get the `WebElement` with `text` set to `Distribution` with any of the following :

- **`CssSelector`**

  ```
  div.tab-tiledViewer.placeholder.tab-widget.fade-in
  ```
- **`Xpath`**

  ```
  //div[@class='tab-tiledViewer placeholder tab-widget fade-in']
  ```

> **But, you can't invoke `click()` method on it. The `WebElement` is a `<div>` tag and doesn't have a `onClick()` event associated with it.**

Answer (score 0):

The CssSelector helped in fixing in my problem.

**This worked :** div[tb-test-id='Distribution']

And I parameterized with a variable by running through foreach loop.

driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div[tb-test-id='" + sheetName + "']")).click();

I appreciate all of your contributions. Thank you very much!